# Getting error while calling class method using Python

Tags: python, encryption, aes

I need to encrypt and decrypt the input text using Python but here I am getting following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "crypto.py", line 21, in <module>
    encrypt = AESCipher()
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

I am providing my code below.

```
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random

class AESCipher:
    def __init__( self, thecarkey ):
        self.key = key

    def encrypt( self, raw ):
        raw = pad(raw)
        iv = Random.new().read( AES.block_size )
        cipher = AES.new( self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv )
        return base64.b64encode( iv + cipher.encrypt( raw ) ) 

    def decrypt( self, enc ):
        enc = base64.b64decode(enc)
        iv = enc[:16]
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv )
        return unpad(cipher.decrypt( enc[16:] ))

encrypt = AESCipher()
passw = encrypt.encrypt('subhra123@')
print(passw)
```

Here I need to encrypt the text using the `Crypto.Cipher` defined inside the class but getting the above error.

Comment: I feel like the error message was obvious enough to solve this issue.  How can you write the code above and not be able to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `AESCipher` requires argument `thecarkey` for object initiation.

so it should be `AESCipher('somekey')`. However there's another bug with your class. The argument `thecarkey` is never used, so I assume it should be just `key`:

```
class AESCipher:
    def __init__( self, key):
        self.key = key
...
encrypt = AESCipher('somekey')
```